# Odd Experience with Screen.AllScreens

Tags: c#

I am working on an application that checks the sizes of all active monitors on a system. I am making a call to the System.Windows.Forms namespace to get an array of monitors.

```
Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
```

The array that it is giving me is incorrect. I have a dual monitor setup, with my Primary display being a laptop monitor and the desktop extends to a secondary monitor. The array that returns seems to have the primary display set to the secondary display. Is there something that I am doing wrong with the call, or is this by design?

**Code that reproduces**

```
Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
foreach (Screen scr in screens)
        {
        //In my case, the display that is primary and called Display 1 is my secondary screen 
        Console.WriteLine("Display Name: " + scr.DeviceName + ", Primary: " + scr.Primary);
        }
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) does not mention anything about the `Screen` array in `AllScreens` being ordered in any way, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that would be fine if there wasn't a string member called DeviceName that in my example is Display1 or Display2 and a boolean called Primary and the secondary monitor is set as the primary and has a DeviceName as Display1

Comment: Excellent. Can you post the code that reproduces this? Close vote is not mine but is (rightfully) asking for it.

Comment: Not sure how to provide code to reproduce, as you have to check the resolution of the screens on your machine, but in my case, the Screen that is set as Primary is the secondary monitor.

Comment: Have you checked whether the laptop display is effectively the primary display (by identifying them using the `desk.cpl` control panel tool)? Also, what @FrédéricHamidi is obviously asking for the code that reproduces it on *your* system, to see if it's the code what is wrong.

Comment: @Isaac, well, we would appreciate an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. A simple console app with calls to `Console.WriteLine()` along with the expected and actual outputs would suffice. Think of it as writing a crude unit test.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Oh i get it, i added a little something.

Comment: @Isaac, thanks. Be sure to double-check the names and the actual primary monitor in your configuration though, as Jcl suggests. The .NET framework usually does not lie about your machine.

Comment: @Jcl it is set as the primary through the screen resolution setting.

Comment: Just a quick thought... Is your secondary desktop extended somehow to the left of the primary?

Comment: No the primary (laptop screen) is the left most monitor

Comment: I definitely can't reproduce here. I've also decompiled the `Screen.AllScreens` property and all it basically does is a `p/invoke` call to `EnumDisplayMonitors` which creates `Screen` objects using the win32's `GetMonitorInfo`, (which checks the `primary` flag correctly). Your system is lying to you, but I don't know why it would have a different result than the `desk.cpl` applet.

Comment: Oh, and I found a duplicate (unanswered) so it **IS** reproducible... I just don't know why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979118/net-thinks-screens-are-ordered-differently-than-windows-control-panel-display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e173fae9-f8b8-4e40-8e36-d255a52fd597/windows-7-getmonitorinfo-returns-wrong-primary?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) may explain a bit what happens, and it seems to be a matter on how the Screen Resolution applet and the API handle the monitors (one seems to be using the registry, while the other queries the driver), and it can happen depending on the order in which you connected your monitors.

Just for correctness (as it was written in the comments), the culprit seems to be the `GetMonitorInfo` function, which is called on the callback to `EnumDisplayMonitors` used by `Screen.AllScreens`.

Basically, there is a mismatch in how Windows stores its own settings to determine what is the primary desktop monitor and how the graphic card driver decides the connected device is the primary monitor.

If you consider this a "bug", then it exists since XP and seems it extends up to Windows 8. It'd not be `Windows.Forms` or `Screens` object bug, it goes down to the `Win32` API level.

I personally don't think it's a *bug*... it's just a bad choice of wording in the documentation for a function, and a lack of a proper API function to achieve what you want, which is "determining what monitor is the primary desktop in", as opposed to "determine which monitor is considered primary": both questions usually have the same answer, but as seems to be the case, there are times and situations where they differ.

I believe you could theoretically parse the registry yourself to determine what Windows considers the primary desktop (which is what you are interested in), but I don't know where to look... probably `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video`, but this is only a wild guess.

I haven't tested it (I'll do it this evening since I'll have access to a box with two not-interconnected different branded graphic cards), but taking this explanation, I presume if there are monitors connected to two different cards (which are not interconnected and using different drivers), you'll actually have more than one "primary" monitor in the `AllScreens` array, unless there's some BIOS things that the driver checks and prevents this to happen (same as when you boot, you don't necessarily see the BIOS screen mirrored across cards and there's only one "primary" monitor even if you have several cards).

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks for the writeup. I think I will go the route of "verifying" by parsing the registry to ensure the primary display is correct. This was very helpful.

Comment: @IsaacLevin i've reasearched since I thought the question was interesting. For an application that needs this, I'd just have a setting telling which desktop coordinates each form goes to and just check if it fits when positioning (or set a default if it doesn't). I'd not relay on "primary" (even "desktop primary") at all for normal usage on an app

Comment: I agree, using the X,Y is the best option. On a side note, I am noticing that the Bounds that Screen.AllScreens is incorrect for my widescreen laptop monitor. The resolution through Windows is set to 1920x1080, but the AllScreens property is 1536x864. I have tried messing with the resolution on the laptop it never seems to match the resolution. I do not have this issue with my standalone monitor which is not widescreen. The laptop monitor itself is 15.5 inch, so that sounds right with the resolution the call is getting, but why does the resolution say otherwise?

Comment: I absolutely have no clue. Your graphic drivers seem to be giving you weird information. Have you tried updating them or otherwise using a different version?